# String Array to Array parse with JSON.parse?

Tags: arrays, json

I have a question. Maybe someone have an idea.
I want to convert a string array with JSON Objects into an array.
Like this:

```
var test = "[{'test1':1,'test2':2},{'test1':1,'test2':2}]";
```

to:

```
var test1 = [{'test1':1,'test2':2},{'test1':1,'test2':2}];
```

my code:

```
var test = "[{'test1':1,'test2':2},{'test1':1,'test2':2}]";
var array = [];
var array = JSON.parse("[" + test + "]");
```

But this code don't work.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks for all.

Comment: That's not JSON syntax. `JSON.parse` expects valid JSON.

Comment: How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Research what JSON syntax rules are. The duplicate references at the top have the info you need. To be specific: keys and string values need to use double quote delimiters, not single quotes.